# How to get the clicked item from MpAndroidChart(UltimateXF) in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, charts, xamarin.forms

I'm using MpAndroidChart(UltimateXF) for my app. I created the piechart successfully but I am unable to create a event listener to get the clicked item when user touched one of piechart item.

**This is my UltimateXF library**

https://nuget.org/packages/UltimateXF/

**This is my code....**

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public HomePage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        var entries = new List<PieEntry>();

        entries.Add(new PieEntry(40, "Life"));
        entries.Add(new PieEntry(60, "General"));

        var dataSet4 = new PieDataSet(entries, "")
        {
            Colors = new List<Color>()
            {
                Color.Accent, Color.Chocolate
            },
            ValueLineColor = Color.Blue,
            SliceSpace = 2f,
            ValueFormatter = new CustomPercentDataSetValueFormatter()
        };
        var data4 = new PieChartData(dataSet4)
        {

        };

        var dataSet5 = new PieDataSet(entries, "")
        {
        };


        pieChart.ChartData = data4;
        pieChart.RotateEnabled = false;

    }
}


public class CustomPercentDataSetValueFormatter : IDataSetValueFormatter
{
    public string GetFormattedValue(float value, int dataSetIndex)
    {
        return value + "%";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have got this problem,can not get the click method from `pieChart`.Maybe this is related to UltimateXF's design.

Comment: no luck at all. if you found any solution please mention here. If I, I will

Comment: Yeah, if find I will .